# Bootstrap 3 Layout Issue

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, row, tabular

I understand how the Bootstrap grid layout works, but I did not see how to handle the rows.

On a medium screen, given rows with `col-md-2` there are six columns of data. As I shift to smaller screens I would like a `col-sm-3` to show four columns of data, and consequently `col-xs-6` to reduce that down to two columns of data on mobile.

The data is pulled from `mysql`, so each column will be different in length (and thus also height). How am I supposed to handle the row `<div class="row">`? Since in `xs` the row will be for two columns, in `sm` it will be for four columns and in `md` it will handle six columns?

I tried removing the row completely and things do not line up properly. Any ideas?

Comment: I know someone will probably ask for code... but for simplicity can we just keep it to conceptual.. so to rephrase how to accomodate row class in bootstrap for different column quantities, since the div with the row class wraps around the divs with the colum class as the quantities of column divs how to we handle the row wrapper.. i hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap handles this exactly the way you want - it will wrap the 'extra' div columns on the smaller devices.  So, the term 'row' is a bit misleading in that it might span several horizontal rows if you are on a smaller device.

You can optionally insert a special clear in between the columns if you have varying heights and you want the tops of the next HORIZONTAL row to line up, e.g.:

```
 <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

Note that the above would insert a clear ONLY on XS devices since 'visible-xs-block' is included in the class list.  If you column elements are the same height, however, this is superflous as the next row will just wraps pleasantly under the previous.

here is a helptile to the the [bootstrap documentation example](http://helptile.com/fs/880) you are looking for:

Comment: It does not work correctly because if I have say 18 columns of data it will show 6 columns on md then 4 and 2, 4 and 2 on sm rather than 4, 4, 4, 4, 2... Makes sense? As the original Row close tags affects... So as a work around I was thinking about having multiple layouts and use css media queries to only show the correct one at the correct break point. Thanks for your prompt answer

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Plunkr for discussion: https://plnkr.co/edit/VlnWhSqyKUdbPCKz4IMh?p=preview (resize to see the responsive behavior)

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>Col 1: </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>Col 2: </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>Col 3: </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>Col 4: </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>Col 5: </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><b>Col 6: </b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy...</div>
  </div>
```

I'm not sure, but I think your question is about how to distribute content into different divs. So, in

- **md:** *all* content in 6 columns
- **sm:** *all* content in just 4 columns
- **xs:** *all* content in just 2 columns

Is this the right understanding? If so, it's not possible to achieve this with Bootstrap 3's grid system.

Comment: Yes, very good that is exactly what I was asking. If Bootstrap 3 is not designed for that flexibility, I guess I could have multiple layouts and use css media queries to only show the correct one at the correct break point. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: Thinking-aloud: Yes, it's possible to create multiple layouts as you describe. The downside is duplicated content on page. Also, that solution don't solve the core problem: to flow content from column to column.

Maybe you can try the css `column-count` property? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts and http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn